# Splash screen doesn't show on boot

Tags: 11.04, grub2, plymouth

Actually, that's slightly misleading, but titles ought to be simple. I have a splash screen:
-For about two seconds during boot, right before the login screen appears.
-During shutdown.

During boot I just see the same purple as used by grub. (Edit: when grub's background is changed, so is the one during boot, so grub seems to be... covering it?)

This has happened since I installed 11.04. 10.04 and 10.10's splashed worked fine for me.

Comment: The boot process in 11.04 brings up the login screen a lot faster than the previous release.  Is the complaint that this doesn't leave much time to see the splash screen?

Comment: Nope, booting still takes about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the solution for me.

First I followed the instructions in the article ["how to fix your Ubuntu splash screen"](http://kyleabaker.com/#search=plymouth).

Then I manually changed the resolutions in `/etc/default/grub` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-24, mtrr=3, scroll=ywrap" ;
```

(do not forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards).

Why, I do not know. In 10.10 it was `1280x1024-24`.

I think it is with the changes in the Ati driver that comes with 11.04.  But I have a nice splash screen at boot time and logoff time now.

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix was found in comment #3 of this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1768725).

I just had too remove "vt.handoff=7" from /etc/grub.d/10_linux (just search/delete) and then run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for me.

First i followed the instructions you can find in the article "how to fix your Ubuntu splash screen".   http://kyleabaker.com/#search=plymouth

Then i had to change manually the resolutions in /etc/default/grub to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-24, mtrr=3, scroll=ywrap" ;

(do not forget sudo update-grub afterwards).

Why, i do not know. In 10.10 it was 1280x1024-24.

I think it is with the changes in the Ati driver that cames with 11.04. But i have a nice splash screen at boot time and logoff time now.

Answer (score -2):

Instal cryptsetup has no influence at all.  I have  found a partial solution at /usr/share/doc/plytmouth : readme.  This is because the driver that permits high-color graphics tends to
cause issues with suspend and resume, and we opted to prefer that
working.

```
For nVidia and ATI users, the default "nouveau" and "radeon"
drivers are Kernel Mode Setting enabled, but do not always
provide 3D capability at the current time.  By switching to
using the restricted/non-free nvidia-glx or fglrx drivers,
you will gain 3D capability at the loss of a high-color
splash screen.
```

You can however chose to enable high-color (and resolution) console
if you find it doesn't affect suspend/resume for you, or you don't
use that feature.

There are various methods of doing this, the most robust is the
following four steps:

Append video=vesafb to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in
   /etc/default/grub
 sudo update-grub

echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
 sudo update-initramfs -u

At the moment i have splash screen in low resolution at startup (always better than black screen) - and normal splash at logout.

Comment: Doing this worked for a few boots, but now the screen is simply shutting off during boot.

Comment: Edit: Ok, it seems to work fine about 50% of the time. The other half the screen shuts of during boot, but turns back on when fully booted.